# function for multiple occurrences in linear search using pointer

Tags: c

This is the code i wrote for multiple occurrences in linear search.Can you please help me point out the mistake ? I want the function to store multiple values in the pointer array and then later to print the array

```
#include <stdio.h>

void linearsearch(int n,int a[n],int x,int count,int *b[count])
{
    count=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            b[j]=i;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    int count;
    int *b[count];
    linearsearch(n,a,x,count,b);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",*b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: `count` contains garbage value!

Comment: @AditiRawat can you please correct the mistake

Comment: Of course it contains garbage values. You're not initializing it to anything.

Comment: `count` is passed by value, so `linearsearch` will not be able to initialize it for you. And, what do you intend `int *b[count]` to be if `count` is not yet initialized?

Comment: `count` being uninitialized is the least of the problems you have. Having `b` be an array of uninitialized pointers is a few steps worse IMO. It really doesn't do what you apparently think it does.

Comment: Can you please help the code with a few edits?

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several errors.

- `count` must be initialized, like `int count = 0;`
- `count` variable is not changed after linearsearch function.
- `b` array should allocated dynamically.

suggested patch is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void linearsearch(int n,int a[n],int x,int *count,int **b)
{
    count=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            *b = realloc(*b, sizeof(int) * (j + 1));
            (*b)[j]=i;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
int count = 0;
int *b = NULL;
linearsearch(n,a,x,&count,&b);
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    printf("%d",b[i]);
}  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost, but if you look carefully, you leak memory horribly because you need to pass an `int **` to the function so that you can change the `int *` in the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Well the ideal way would be to allocate the memory dynamically  based of the number of `x` found. But well let's look at the errors first. Maybe after this discussion you can write the code.

```
b[j]=i;
```

In the called function let's dissect the type of this.

`i` is of type `int`. And `b[j]` is of type `int*`. Then you assigned them (type mismatched). Then `%d` expects an `int` but you passed something of type `int*`. This is undefined behavior.

Now there was another flaw you had - you passed `count` and somehow you expect the value you changed in `search` will be there in `main()`. C is pass by value and you changed to a local variable. That change is  lost when the called function ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int* linearsearch(int n,int* a,int x,int* count)
{
    *count=0;
    if( n <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error" );
        exit(1);
    }
    int *t = malloc(sizeof(*t)*n);
    if( t == NULL){
        perror("Malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(a[i] == x)
            t[(*count)++] = i;
    int *temp = realloc(t,sizeof(*temp)* (*count));
    if( temp == NULL){
        perror("Realloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    t = temp;
    return t;
}
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    if( scanf("%d",&n)!= 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input");
        exit(1);
    }
    if( n <= 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input : must be greater than 0");
        exit(1);   
    }
    int a[n];

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        if(scanf("%d",&a[i])!=1){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in input." );
            exit(1);
        }

    int elmt_to_find;
    if( scanf("%d",&elmt_to_find)!= 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input : Element to find(must be integer)");
    }
    int count;
    int *b = linearsearch(n,a,elmt_to_find,&count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
    printf("%s","\n");
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with using VLA for `b`, you can alter your `linearsearch` to return `count` only if `b` is NULL. Then, you can create `b` as VLA, and pass it back to `linearsearch` again to be populated.

```
int count = linearsearch(n, a, x, 0, 0);
int b[count];
linearsearch(n, a, x, count, b);
```

Then, your function could look like:

```
int linearsearch(int n,int a[n],int x,int count,int *b[count])
{
    int i;
    if(count==0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==x)
            {
                count+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (b==0)
    {
        return count;
    }
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==x)
        {
            b[j]=i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```